# User and roles models associations - naming conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have two models: User and UserType. I want to make one-to-many relationship between them. This is my code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_type
end
class UserType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

In my database I added `user_type_id` to users table. I named my model files as `user.rb` and `user_type.rb`.

I am trying to assign user to the user type in my console, but it`s not working. I suppose I have some naming convention error here...

```
@user  = User.first 
@user.user_type = UserType.first
```

I get an error: `method missing => user_type`

But this works:

```
@type = UserType.first
@type.users = User.first
```

Comment: Try @user.user_type_id = UserType.first.id

Comment: Unfortunately no.. but thank for suggestion

Comment: Using user_type_id threw the same error? That seems like the migration didn't go through or has an error

Comment: Are you sure you ran the migration to add the column user_type_id?

Comment: Yeah, my users table have user_type_id column in schema..

Comment: but this works

    user = User.first
    type = UserType.first
    type.users = @user